Download from Overpass API and convert to geojson with python
I want to download some data data from die OSM Overpass API and convert this data to geojson with Python.
I have prepared an example with an multipolygon. My UseCase has much bigger files.
The download part is working but in the transformation I see this error below.
But in the frontend I see this polygon and I need it also in the geojson.
Best
Failed to create multipolygon. Base shape with role "outer" is invalid. Group ids: [431444168,
 431444172,
 431444165,
 431444166,
 431444160,
 431444162,
 431444176,
 1175053062,
 431444159,
 431444167,
 431444173,
 431444164,
 431444155,
 431444158,
 431444156,
 431444169,
 431444163,
 431444175,
 431444174]
Failed to convert computed shapes to multipolygon 6417656
Element not converted 6417656

import osm2geojson
import codecs
import os
import json
import requests
from pathlib import Path


myinput_path = r"C:\tmp_geo"
myinput_filename="IT2.json"
myoutput_filename=myinput_filename.replace(".json",".geojson")


os.makedirs(myinput_path, exist_ok=True)

myinput=os.path.join(myinput_path,myinput_filename)
myoutput=os.path.join(myinput_path,myoutput_filename)

def download_osm_data(query, filepath_osm):
    useragent = 'YourAppName/ContactInfo'
    headers = {'User-Agent': useragent, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    data = {'data': query}
    try:
        response = requests.post('https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter', headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
        response.raise_for_status()
        with open(Path(filepath_osm), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(response.text)
        return True
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Download error: {e}")


query = f"""
                [out:json][timeout:25];
                (
                relation["boundary"="protected_area"]["type"="multipolygon"](43.1851, 9.6689, 44.4386, 11.3216);
                );
                out geom;

                """

download_osm_data(query, myinput)

with codecs.open(myinput, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as data:
    inputdata = data.read()

geojsondata=osm2geojson.json2geojson(inputdata, filter_used_refs=False, log_level='INFO')

with open(myoutput, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(geojsondata, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)


Relation 6417656 looks correct to me. Two inner members, a closed outer ring. Maybe the problem is that the python library can't handle multipolygons if the outer members aren't sorted correctly, which is the case here. Sounds like a bug in the library.

hhmmm ok. Do you may have an idea how I could transform data like this to a geojson (or shp) without open in QGIS and do a manuell Export?

I think https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson is a popular converter.
